# Have an HTML load a JS file from different places, depending on environment

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

How can I have my `index.html` load a JS file from different places, depending on my environment?

On development I want the `src` of my file to be an absolute path: `/dist/bundle.js`

In production, I want the `src` of my file to be a relative path: `dist/bundle.js`

Here is the HTML where the file is loaded:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'>
    </div>
    <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If it is helpful, I am using Webpack.

Comment: In general, the best solution is to change your development environment to match your production environment (or vise versa). Each thing that is different between the two is yet one more thing that can go wrong when moving code from development into production.  I'm aware that's not the solution you are looking for here. But, it should be mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mentioned that webpack is being used, I'm assuming a different configuration is used for development and production.

You could try the [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) and set it up to inject the script in your `index.html` file. This way the script will be injected into HTML based on the webpack output setup. You might have to adjust your config accordingly. If that doesn't work, the [webpack-path-rewriter](https://github.com/skozin/webpack-path-rewriter) seems as an option too, but I haven't tried it yet.

Or you could write a small script that would determine the environment based on `document.location.hostname` and then include a `<script>` with correct src path. But this approach just doesn't seem right and is prone to changing domains.

But I would agree with what @Makyen, make environments the same. I assume the production one would be more difficult to change, so try to match that one with whatever you're doing in development.